# Traversing TEI in Python 3, text comes up empty for some entities

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, tail, tei

I have a TEI-encoded xml file with entities as follows:

```
<sp>
    <speaker rend="italic">Sampson.</speaker>
    <ab>
         <lb n="5"/>
         <hi rend="italic">Gregory:</hi>
         <seg type="homograph">A</seg> my word wee'l not carry coales.<lb n="6"/>
    </ab>
</sp>
<sp>
     <speaker rend="italic">Greg.</speaker>
     <ab>No, for then we should be Colliars.
         <lb n="7" rend="rj"/>
     </ab>
</sp>
```

The full file is very large but can be accessed here: http://ota.ox.ac.uk/desc/5721. I'm attempting to use Python 3 to traverse the xml and get all the text associated with the  tag, which is where the dialogue is found.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
tree = etree.parse('romeo_juliet_5721.xml')
doc = tree.getroot()
for i in doc.iter(tag='{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}ab'):   
        print(i.tag, i.text)
>>> http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}ab 
>>>                  
>>> {http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}ab No, for then we should be Colliars.
```

The output catches the  entities just fine but doesn't recognize "my word wee'l not carry coales" as the text of the first ab. If it's within a different element, I'm not seeing it. I've thought about converting the entire element to a string and getting the element text using regex (or by stripping all xml tags), but I would rather understand what's happening here. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in the `ElementTree` model, the text *" my word wee'l not carry coales."* is considered *`tail`* of `<seg>` element instead of *`text`* of `<ab>`. To get the text of an element as well as tail of its children, you can try this way :

```
for i in doc.iter(tag='{http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0}ab'): 
    innerText = i.text+''.join((text.tail or '') for text in i.iter()).strip()  
    print(i.tag, innerText)
```