# Why is text of HTML node empty with HTMLParser?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, html5lib

In the following example I am expecting to get `Foo` for the `<h2>` text:

```
from io import StringIO
from html5lib import HTMLParser

fp = StringIO('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <h2>
            <span class="section-number">1. </span>
            Foo
            <a class="headerlink" href="#foo">¶</a>
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
''')

etree = HTMLParser(namespaceHTMLElements=False).parse(fp)
h2 = etree.findall('.//h2')[0]

h2.text
```

Unfortunately I get `''`. Why?

Strangly, foo is in the text:

```
>>> list(h2.itertext())
['1. ', 'Foo', '¶']

>>> h2.getchildren()
[<Element 'span' at 0x7fa54c6a1bd8>, <Element 'a' at 0x7fa54c6a1c78>]

>>> [node.text for node in h2.getchildren()]
['1. ', '¶']
```

So where is `Foo`?

Comment: why are you expecting "Foo" when h2 contains no text. the child element _span_ on the other hand, does.

Comment: @BlueRineS `<span>` is closed before `Foo` so `Foo` is not in `<span>`...

Comment: @BlueRineS I have edited my question, I do not find `Foo` in `span`. Yes I have search into the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are one level too shallow in the tree. Try this:

```
from io import StringIO
from html5lib import HTMLParser

fp = StringIO('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <h2>
            <span class="section-number">1. </span>
            Foo
            <a class="headerlink" href="#foo">¶</a>
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
''')

etree = HTMLParser(namespaceHTMLElements=False).parse(fp)
etree.findall('.//h2')[0][0].tail
```

More generally, to crawl all text and tail, try a loop like this:

```
for u in etree.findall('.//h2')[0]:
    print(u.text, u.tail)
```

Comment: Ok I understand, but I don't understand... :) It seems `Foo` is part of `span.tail` despite it is ouside of `span`.

Comment: @nowox - It does seem like a parsing error. If you parse the html with lxml, you find `Foo` inside the `h2` text, as it should be.

Comment: @JackFleeting Do you mean `HTMLParser` is buggy?

Comment: @nowox - That may well be the case, though I don't know enough about it to be definitive. I can say that lxml's default parser works as expected.

Comment: @JackFleeting How would you modify my example to use lxml?

Comment: @nowox - sure; see answer below (or above, no idea where SO is going to stick it...)

Comment: @nowox I think you've misunderstood how `ElementTree` represents data: `el.text` is the child of the element if it is a text node; `el.tail` is the following sibling to the element if it is a text node. See also, e.g., [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062825/traversing-tei-in-python-3-text-comes-up-empty-for-some-entities/37063050) and [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text).

Answer (score 0):

Using lxml:

```
fp2 = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body>
        <h2>
            <span class="section-number">1. </span>
            Foo
            <a class="headerlink" href="#foo">¶</a>
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
'''

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(fp2)

for item in tree.xpath('//h2'):
    target = item.text_content().strip()
    print(target.split('\n')[1].strip())
```

Output:

> Foo

Comment: Thanks :) So I wasn't using the same libary then (`from lxml import etree`)

Comment: @nowox - no; they just sound the same :)

Comment: Note that the tree `lxml` produces here is no different to the one `html5lib` produces; the "foo" becomes the `item.children[0].tail` in the above code, so this doesn't answer why the it's not in `item.text`.

Comment: @gsnedders - I have no idea what you're talking about; OP asked for an `lxml` solution, not for an answer to what you think is the question.

Comment: OP asked why it wasn't in `h2.text` (which you don't answer), and "where is Foo?" (which, okay, you get from `h2.text_content()`, but it's unsurprising it appears in the sum of all of the text node descendants). You claimed in a comment this was a parsing error with html5lib, despite it appearing in the same place in lxml.

Comment: @gsnedders -  No, op just asked "@JackFleeting How would you modify my example to use lxml?", which is what I did - but whatever.